# Why does this NodeJS code return empty response object?

Tags: node.js, express

This is the code:

```
router.post("/form", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { name, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (!user) return res.status(501).send("Something went wrong");
    let token = await user.getSignedToken();
    console.log(token); //Server logs this

user.emailToken = await user.verifyEmail();// This property is not being added in the saved mongodb document. It should, but again idk why it's not

    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
    console.log(user); // Server doesn't log this
    const options = {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
    };
    console.log(options); // Server doesn't log this
    res.cookie("token", token, options);
    res.send("Check email for activation");
  } catch (ex) {
    res.send(ex);
  }
});
```

Below is the verifyEmail method (in userSchema.. I'm using mongoose):

```
userSchema.methods.verifyEmail = async function () {
  let emailToken = this._id + crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex");
  let emailTokenHashed = await crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(passwordToken)
    .digest("hex");
  this.emailToken = emailTokenHashed;

  return emailToken;
};
```

Now, it should send "Check email for activation", right? But, it's sending an empty response object. Also, if you see in the code, the server is logging only one console.log (i.e. the first console.log). But, it is sending a cookie (I checked via postman). So, what's the issue here?

Comment: You do not need to await ``crypto`` while creating a hash. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but why not just call `this.save()` in your Schema method instead of doing `user.emailToken = await user.verifyEmail()` and then the saving? Or you could also just do `await user.verifyEmail()` without setting it to `user.emailToken` because it's already set in the Schema method or isn't it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @jfriend00 no it doesn't. it's sending an empty object as response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sends `res.send("Check email for activation");` or `res.send(ex);`.  Since you say that:

```
console.log(options); // Server doesn't log this
```

then one of your `await` statements must be hitting a rejected promise and sending you to the `catch`.  Add `console.log(ex)` right before `res.send(ex)` to see what the error is so you have this:

```
} catch (ex) {
    console.log("got error", ex);
    res.send(ex);
}
```

And, then see what you get in the log.

In general you never want to send an error object directly because most of its properties are non-enumerable so they won't get sent as JSON and that may make the error object completely **empty** when it gets converted to JSON and thus isn't useful to the client at all.  Instead, log the error on your server and send a 500 status:

```
res.sendStatus(500);
```

Or, if you want to send an error object construct your own error object with regular, enumerable properties and send that.

Anyway, once you add the `console.log(ex)` to your server, it should tell you what the actual rejected promise is and that will show you what's going wrong with the request.  ALWAYS log errors on the server to help you see and solve problems like this.

Comment: first of all, I'm receiving an empty object as response. Secondly, I tried console.log(ex) but it doesn't log any exception

Comment: @Zain763 - What exactly does `console.log(ex)` log?   Your code only has two places you're sending a response.  One sends a string, the other sends an object.  If you're getting an object back from the response, logic would say that you're hitting the code path that sends the object.  You need to debug why that is.

Comment: console.log(ex) is not logging anything at all. That's what I don't understand. It doesn't log 2 console log statements. It doesn't log exception. It doesn't send the desired response but it is setting the cookie. That's the problem that I don't understand. Been working on it for hours.

Comment: @Zain763 - Put `console.log(...)` statements between every single statement in this handler and see EXACTLY where the code flow is going.,  Or, start up in the debugger, set a breakpoint at the start of the request handler and trace through it.  You need to see EXACTLY what the code flow is here.

Comment: the only thing getting logged is the token

Comment: @Zain763 - Then, either `await user.verifyEmail();` or `await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });` must be rejecting/throwing.  You have to figure out which one is and capture the error message from it to see why.  You can surround each with their own `try/catch` with their own separate error logging to make sure their error gets output and so you can see which one is getting hit.

Comment: so added console logs in everything. It's only logging the user and token. I don't know how to do debugging or set breakpoints so I cant try that

Comment: @Zain763 - Did you see my previous comment that explains the next diagnostic step?

Comment: It worked. I wrapped up both of thise lines that you said in try/catch blocks and it seems I was using a var that didn't exist in user.verifyEmail() method. So, that was sending me promise rejection. I've changed that now and now the code works and I get the desired response. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @Zain763 - Please also change your code so you're not doing `res.send(ex);` in the `catch` because that isn't going to be useful to the caller.  You should send an error status.